# Как правильно сделать фон веб-страницы в данном примере?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как сделать все семантически правильно (т.е. без лишних div'ов и т.п.)? На данный момент есть правило в css:

```
html {background-image: url('../images/news.jpg'); 
      background-repeat: no-repeat; 
      background-attachment: fixed;
     }
```

Проблемы:

1. Как правильно настроить высоту картинки\фона? Размер картинки: 1200 x 1550. Нужно чтобы картинка правильно (т.е. во всю ширину и высоту) отображалась на большинстве экранов с самыми разными разрешениями (именно поэтому она такая высокая)
   Важен случай, когда картинка > экрана по высоте. Например, как у меня (15 дюймов, 1280 x 800) картинка видна не полностью, а лишь та часть которая вмещается на экран. В таком случае возникает проблема добавления футера: футер уехал в самый низ картинки, т.е. его на экране не видно.
2. Как правильно сделать фон для более широких экранов, чем мой? Растянуть фон - вроде бы это неправильно тк исказиться изображение. Если сделать шире фон, то как его настроить для большинства экранов чтобы отображался фон во всю ширину ?
3. Я пытаюсь работать с фоном размером около 1-1,5 Мб. Не слишком ли это много для браузеров интернета (т.е. может придется долго ждать пока загрузиться вся веб-страничка) ?

Answer (score 4):

1. Правильно настроить высоту можно либо создав фоны для [всех разрешений](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e5/Vector_Video_Standards2.svg)(их не так много), либо используя `<img src="" />`. Растяжение/сжатие фонового изображения - фишка css3, посему поддерживается отнюдь не всеми браузерами.
2. см выше.
3. Это офигительно много. Для ФОНОВОЙ картинки в 2 мегапикселя (1920х1080) можно уложиться в 300-600кб. Это много еще и потому, что при изменении размера средствами HTML, быстро работать она будет только на браузерах с поддержкой аппаратного ускорения.

Comment: Если создавать фоны для всех разрешений, то, как я понимаю, придется программно определять (с помощью Javascript, например) разрешение клиента, и вставлять соответствующий фон. Неужели нельзя обойтись только средствами css и html?

Comment: Можно. Я уже написал, как и какие будут трудности. "Вниз", на фон - `img`, у него задана высота и ширина. `src` - самый большой рисунок (по самому большому разрешению). Вверх - див-канва с большим `z-index` или большим отрицательным маргином, который содержит остальной сайт. Тормознуто будет, я гарантирую это.

Comment: Дело в том, что я стараюсь придерживаться правил семантической вертски, по которым нельзя просто так вставить img в html для оформления (что то вроде принципа).
Вопрос по ширине решился тем, что сделал картинку пошире и выравнял ее по центру: html {...; background-position: center top;...}
Остается проблема по высоте: картинка больше размеров экрана, и мне нужно как бы "обрезать" ее на том месте, где экран заканчивается, но так, чтобы можно было нормально прикрепить блок футера внизу страницы..

Comment: Картинку увидеть бы!

Comment: Обрезать можно, вставив картинку в блок, у которого указать overflow: hidden.
насчет принципов верстки не очень понял. :)

Comment: Как сюда картинку то вставить (в вопрос)? :)  Не получилось - пробовал 2 раза: назвал ссылку bg, загрузил с компа - ничего не вывелось в вопрос кроме тегов.

Про принципы вертски (кстати, очень полезный материал) - вот [здесь](http://webstandards.org.ru/blog/layout/web-standards.html).

Comment: 300-699кб фон?<br>
пожалейте пользователей с медленым интернет соединением...

Comment: Вот я и жалею. =) Заметте: это уже не 1-1,5мб!   
Я вообще считаю, что вся страница должна быть не более 50кб для чего-то типа статичных контактов, 100кб для статьи с кликабельными иллюстрациями и 300кб для сложной страницы веб-приложения. Но кто же меня слушает? =)

Comment: А зачем?<br>
<pre><code>background-position:canter;
background-image:url...;</code></pre><br><br>
И пусть браузеры сами разруливают...

Comment: Конечно есть:

    style="overflow: hidden"

или

    style="clip:rect(0px,60px,200px,0px);"

А вообще, кто-то там радел за качество и стандарты оформления. Так вот, по ним это все должно быть в  CSS там, в стайлсах

Comment: background-size: cover; пробовали?

Comment: Верно. Спустя 5 лет, мой ответ уже неактуален :) Сейчас CSS3 поддерживается почти всеми.

Answer (score 1):

Надеюсь, что это универсальное решение, которое получится использовать и в дальнейшем. Итак, чтобы сделать фон, который подойдет к различным разрешениям, надо:

- По высоте и по ширине сделать картинку максимально большой (например, 2000 x 1550 как у меня). Дальше нужно выровнять картинку по центру:

  ```
  html {
    background-image: url('../images/news.jpg'); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top; overflow: hidden;
  }
  ```
- Чтобы браузеру не пришлось долго загружать картинку, сжать ее (мне удалось сжать ее с ~1,5Mb до ~500Kb)
- Осталось прикрутить футер к низу страницы (`position: absolute; bottom: 0;`)

Answer (score 1):

> Осталось прикрутить футер к низу экрана так, чтобы при любых условиях он оставался внизу экрана (пока не знаю как это сделать).

Нужно, что бы футер был всегда внизу и виден? position: fixed; bottom: 0px;

Это будет хорошо для маленького футера - информера.

или футер должен быть привязан к низу картинки?

Comment: Спасибо! Уже футер привязал: position: absolute; bottom: 0;
Так он располагается внизу страницы, в не окна браузера.